# Search directory for specific string

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm trying to search through a specific directory full of header files, and look through each header file, and if any file has a string "struct" in it, I just want the program to print which file has it.

I have this so far, but it's not working correctly, can you help me figure it out:

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir( "C:/headers" )
for files in glob.glob( "*.h" ):
    f = open( files, 'r' )
    for line in f:
        if "struct" in line:
            print( f )
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: Please define 'not working correctly'

Comment: It's not printing anything, even though I have plenty of .h files with the line struct in there.

Comment: are you looping through the files?: for line in f: print(line)

Comment: The for loop lets you work on one file at a time, thus is should be `for file ...` (singular, yes, I am nick picking, but it helps with the strain of thought.) Secondly, you should close a file after finish reading it. I recommend using the `with` construct to automatically close files. Third, f is a file handle, not a filename (string), so `print file` instead of `print f`.

Comment: An optimization - once the string is found (after the `print`), stop the loop with `break` - you know at this stage the file has the line, no need to spend cycles on the rest of its content.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you are interested in the file name, not the line, so we can speed thing up by reading the whole file and search:

```
...
for file in glob.glob('*.h'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'struct' in contents:
        print file
```

Using the `with` construct ensures the file to be closed properly. The f.read() function reads the whole file.

#### Update

Since the original poster stated that his code was not printing, I suggest to insert a  debugging line:

```
...
for file in glob.glob('*.h'):
    print 'DEBUG: file=>{0}<'.format(file)
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'struct' in contents:
        print file
```

If you don't see any line that starts with 'DEBUG:', then your glob() returned an empty list. That means you landed in a wrong directory. Check the spelling for your directory, along with the directory's contents.

If you see the 'DEBUG:' lines, but don't see the intended output, your files might not have any 'struct' in in. Check for that case by first cd to the directory, and issue the following DOS command:

```
find "struct" *.h
```

Comment: I assume 'OP'=original poster. There are two things: 1. print(f) ==> f is a file handle, not a file name, 2. The code will print the same file several times, each for every occurrence of 'struct'. My code only prints out the file name once.

Comment: Yes i got that, but why his version wasn't printing anything?

Comment: So I've done this, and it works.. I'm honestly not sure why mine didn't work. And I'm a her, btw. :) But I really don't know what's going on. I'm not really able to debug it well either considering I literally just started Python today.

Comment: @chakolatemilk, I tested your original code, and it works for me. I believe there was some mistake, which you didn't reproduce in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This works when I test it on my end:

```
for files in glob.glob( "*.h" ):
    f = open( files, 'r' )
    file_contents = f.read()
    if "struct" in file_contents:
            print f.name
    f.close()
```

Make sure you print `f.name`, otherwise you're printing the file object, and not the name of the file itself.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that not cause an infinite loop on a non-empty line and not even loop all the lines in the file?

Comment: Right, there's some problems with it, fixing it up now.

Comment: @akalIDIOT: I've updated it, does that look like it would work?

Comment: this does the same as in the question. his problem is not in the file iteration

Comment: @Nate if unsure, test it out for yourself locally... (and, as RickyA states, that doesn't do anything different than OP's version)

Comment: @RickyA: True, I've updated it to include `f.name`, and tested it on my end. Works as expected.