# Finding many strings in directory

Tags: python, csv, directory

I have a directory full of files and a set of strings that need identification(about 40). I want to go through all of the files in the directory and print out the names of the files that have any one of my strings. I found code that works perfectly ([Search directory for specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710918/python-search-directory-for-specific-string)), but it only works for one string. Whenever I try to add more, it prints out the name of every single file in the directory. Can someone help me tweak the code as I just started programming a few days ago and don't know what to do.

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'string' in contents:
        print file
```

That code was taken from the question I mentioned above. Any help would be appreciated and any tips on asking the question better would as well! Thank You!

Comment: What is the expected result? The list of files that contains at least one of the strings or the list of files which contain all of the strings?

Comment: @sashkello: At least one..

Comment: Then @Bonifacio2 answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import glob
strings = ['string1', 'string2']
for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    for string in strings:
        if string in contents:
            print file
            break
```

About asking better questions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `grep`:

```
$ grep -l -f strings.txt *.csv
```

Comment: I am a bit new to this, can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: but grep isn't python